# Gnome terminal doesn't recognise commands when started from startup-applications with .sh file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ros, gnome-terminal

I am trying to use an .sh script to start a terminal when ubuntu boots. Gnome-terminal successfully starts up but when commands start executing such as (roscore, roslaunch or rosrun) it displays an error as follows: "bash: roslaunch command not found". Is there any way to fix this problem or any other way to start launch files of ROS with a visible terminal at start?

This is how my .sh file looks like

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal --geometry=40x40  \
--tab --title="roscore" -e "bash -c \"source ~/.bashrc;roscore;exec bash\"" \
--tab --title="navigation" -e "bash -c  \"sleep 38;roslaunch navigation.launch;exec bash\"" \
--tab --title="robot" -e "bash -c  \"sleep 28;roslaunch robot_config.launch;exec bash\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sourcing ros setup.bash file (source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash)? If not just add it to ~/.bashrc file